# Issue with Building Java Application in Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, deployment, build

I am at the Java Directory. And When I execute the build command:
docker build -t karthikjohnbabu/hello-world-java:0.0.2.RELEASE .

I get the below error message. Please help me???

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:195e9c227ad891282e80602cac2372a3085ecf4ceefbb395558ffe0f7bb0b9aa: not found.

Complete details of error below:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images. Also please go ahead and post your dockerfile in order to troubleshoot.

Comment: Editing the question to include a [mcve] would also be helpful.  "no match for platform in manifest" could suggest a CPU architecture problem; are you using an M1 Mac, or an ARM system, or something else that's not x86-based?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the following arg to the command:

```
   --platform=linux/amd64
```

or alternatively use the following command to set an env var:

```
   export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

The information you gave leaves room for guessing.

I believe the important part is `no match for platform in manifest`.
Thus I believe in your dockerfile you start `FROM someimage`, and this someimage is not available for the platform you are using (which could mean MacOS).